# Using QThread and moveToThread properly with QTimer and QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

From reading this [blog](http://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/), this [blog](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) and some others, Subclassing QThread is bad practice. So I tried to apply this method.

But my problem is that I have a QTimer and a QTcpSocket in the class I want to move to a different thread. Suddenly, it's not as easy as it the examples used. :(

```
QThread m_commsThread;
m_pICommsHandler = new CommsHandlerIP();
m_pICommsHandler->moveToThread(&m_commsThread);
m_commsThread.start();
```

And here is the CommsHandlerIP class, methods are not included.

```
class CommsHandlerIP : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CommsHandlerIP();
    ~CommsHandlerIP(void);
protected:
    QTcpSocket m_TCPSocket;
    QTimer m_timer;
}
```

Issue is that the QTimer and the QTcpSocket (inside CommsHandlerIP class) are in the main thread even if you move CommsHandlerIP. So I can't start the timer or connect the socket.

If I try to moveToThread the QTimer and QTcpSocket (inside the constructor by passing the thread pointer for instance), this become really messy when I leave the app.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class Instances are created on the calling thread.
`QTimer` inherits `QObject`.
Each Thread on `Qt` can have an event loop if it calls `exec()`.
so you want to move `QTimer` to an event loop on another thread.
so you should manually move it.

Therefore, delay their creation until after you move the object: -

```
class CommsHandlerIP : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public slots:
       void Initialise();

    private: 
       void Run();

       // c++ 11, initialising in headers...
       QTimer* m_pTimer = NULL;
       QTcpSocket* m_pSocket = NULL;   
};

void CommsHandlerIP::Initialise()
{
     m_pTimer = new QTimer(this);
     m_pSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);

     Run();
}

QThread m_commsThread;
m_pICommsHandler = new CommsHandlerIP();

// Note Qt 5 connect style
connect(&m_commsThread, &QThread::started, m_pICommsHandler, &CommsHandlerIP::Initialise);
m_pICommsHandler->moveToThread(&m_commsThread);
m_commsThread.start();
```

When the thread is started, the `CommsHanderIP` *Initialise* function is called; this is where you should create and setup the `QTcpSocket` and `QTimer` objects before calling `Run()`. As the `CommsHandlerIP` is running in the new thread before creating those objects, they will also share the same thread affinity.

Comment: I feel so stupid, I knew what was the problem but I tried to fix it in a compltely wrong way

Comment: It's easy when you know how ;O)

Comment: If you've passed a parent to the QTcpSocket, it will be deleted along with its parent; such is the power of parent / child hierarchy in Qt.

Comment: Passing `this` as a parent to `m_TCPSocket` and `m_timer` when creating them in the constructor would be sufficent. This is because [QObject::moveToThread()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#moveToThread) `changes the thread affinity for this object and its children`. So you don't have to delay their creation.

Comment: True, but problems can occur later, if connections to signals / slots have been made to them before they have been moved. The connection type created depends upon the thread affinity of the caller and callee.

Comment: Actually it ins't enough. If I close the main thread (and thus closing the worker thread), then for some reasons, it won't work. (can't send event to the socket from a different thread, even though this is in the destructor of the CommsHandler).

Comment: Define "won't work". You should be stopping the other threads (call quit) and waiting for them to finish before terminating the application.

Comment: in the main thread (the QMainWindow), i have m_commsThread.quit() and m_commsThread.wait() and then delete m_pICommsHandler; (object moved to the other thread)
I managed to fix the issue by calling the destruction of the socket just before the main thread is exited.

Comment: @Merlin069 AFAIK, if the type is `Qt::AutoConnection`, it shouldn't matter if the connection is established before `moveToThread()` is called. This is because `If the signal is emitted from a different thread than the receiving object, the signal is queued, behaving as Qt::QueuedConnection. Otherwise, the slot is invoked directly, behaving as Qt::DirectConnection. The type of connection is determined when the signal is emitted`.

Comment: Thuga is right. By using this, I don't need to delay the initialisation of the socket and of the timers.
The destructor issue remains in this case though.

Comment: @thuga, just checked and you're right, the docs state "The type of connection is determined when the signal is emitted." Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled across this when searching on Timer behaviour and movetoThread. 
The accepted answer is a good work-around but not really the root cause of the problem. There is a general rule that when you move an object then all child objects will move as well. So you just need to make sure that the QTimer becomes a child so pass the this pointer in its constructor.

```
CommsHandlerIPL::CommsHandlerIP()
: QObject(), m_pTimer(new QTimer(this))        // <=== crucial to make it a "child" object 
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler method of achieving all this that follows the same algorithm but doesn't involve all the boilerplating needed to create threads and changing thread affinities, using [QRunnable](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qrunnable.html) and [QThreadPool](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthreadpool.html)

If I convert Merlin069's example, you'll see how it simplifies the code a bit:

```
class CommsHandlerIP : public QObject, public QRunnable
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
       void run();

    public slots:
        //... any slots

    signals:
        //... any signals

    private:
       // c++ 11, initialising in headers...
       QTimer* m_pTimer = NULL;
       QTcpSocket* m_pSocket = NULL;   
};

void CommsHandlerIP::run()
{
     m_pTimer = new QTimer();
     m_pSocket = new QTcpSocket();

     //...

     delete m_pTimer;
     delete m_pSocket;
}

QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(new CommsHandlerIP);
```