# How can I make my waitForBytesWritten call non blocking ?

Tags: qt, qt4

I have this function :

```
bool TCPClient::sendPacket(Protocol::Packet &packet)
{
  if(this->tcpSocket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
  {
    std::cout << "writing ..." << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(BabelPacket) + packet.dataLength << std::endl;
    this->tcpSocket->write((const char *)&packet, sizeof(Protocol::BabelPacket) + packet.dataLength);
    return this->tcpSocket->waitForBytesWritten(-1);
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "socket close" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
}
```

But when I called it, it blocks my GUI.

Have you got an idea how I can make this call non blocking, and still have the readyRead signal triggered ?

Thanks

Comment: Listen for the `bytesWritten()` signal instead.

Comment: When you don't want to block the GUI, you don't run the blocking operations on GUI thread. You can create another QThread, and use `QObject::moveToThread(...)` method

Comment: @MrEricSir What do you mean ? ` I did   connect(this->tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(readMessage())); ` But when the server sends me a packet, the readMessage function isn't triggered

Comment: @Rinold So, I need to do a moveToThread everytime I need to do waitForBytesWritten ?

Comment: @DimitriDanilov, you should move objects to another thread once, here you can find [some example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252608/using-qthread-and-movetothread-properly-with-qtimer-and-qtcpsocket). The idea is to separate the long running operations from the GUI thread.

Comment: @DimitriDanilov `readyRead()` and `bytesWritten()` are not the same signal.

Comment: @MrEricSir I understand that, readyRead is triggered when a socket receive data, and bytesWritten when a socket send a data, right ?

Comment: @DimitriDanilov As per the docs, "This signal is emitted every time a payload of data has been written to the device." Also note that `waitForBytesWritten()` simply blocks until that signal is fired.